# Mouse event with RadPageView

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a problem with RadPageView on catch mouse event when I'm building an app using Telerik UI for WinForms.

I just want to catch mouseover event of some page in a page view. In this case, I want to show the content while a page header is under pointer.

For example, I have a page view named "Page" and it has 2 pages are "A" and "B". I want to show these page's content when the pointer point to them.

Please give me a solutions for this case.
Thanks, 
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Could you please release codes that you've tried to achieve this, put codes to correct. you will get better answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
    private void RadPageView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RadPageViewItem hoveredItem = radPageView1.ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(e.Location) as RadPageViewItem;
        if (hoveredItem != null)
        {
            radPageView1.SelectedPage = hoveredItem.Page;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `e.location` was not behaving properly in some corner cases (multiple pages were getting hovered if we moved cursor in a certain way).

I used below logic (use of `isMouseOver` property of each item) and it works perfectly:

```cs
private void RadPageView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    foreach (RadPageViewPage pageView in radPageView1.Pages) {

        if (!pageView.Item.IsMouseOver) {
            //your logic for hovered pages
        } else {
            //your logic (if any) for non-hovered pages
        }
        
    }
}
```